# How to bulk insert the parsed html table data in database in coldfusion?

Tags: sql, database, coldfusion, bulkinsert, batch-insert

I am new in programming and got stuck in a task to insert the parsed html table data into the database. I have tried this link [bulk insert in coldfusion](https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2017/11/bulk-inserting-data) but It is not working.

I think my case is different. Here is my code.

```
sql = '';
records = '';
while(i<rows_length){
     // <cfif i NEQ 1 && home_lineup NEQ 1>,</cfif>
     writeoutput('<tr>');
    for(j=1; j<cols_length; j++){
            stat_cell = get_lineup.select('##sl-away-lineup-table tr:eq(#i#) td:eq(#j#)').text();

        //records =records & #stat_cell# & ',';
         // <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#users[u].firstname#">,
         // <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#users[u].lastname#">,
         // <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#users[u].email#">,
         // <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#users[u].firstname#">,
         // <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#users[u].firstname#">,
         // <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#users[u].firstname#">,
         // <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#users[u].lastname#">,
         // <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#users[u].email#">,
         // <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#users[u].lastname#">,
         // <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#users[u].email#">,
        writeoutput('<td>#stat_cell#</td>'); // this is the cell data I want to batch/bulk insert each cell data 
        records = records& #stat_cell# &','; //it is not a good idea i think to concat like this

    }
}
```

I have no idea how to know that which cell is of which datatype so that I can pass in query param but the other question is that how to make a query(concat or anything else) so that I can insert in database?

Note: This code is written in cfscript but you can provide suggestion other than cfscript.

Comment: When you say `parsed html table data` what kind of a thing are you talking about? Normally we query DBs to generate HTML tables, not the other way around. I really really you are not suggesting that you took an HTML table that is also valid XML and you want to load it into a DB table.

Comment: @JamesAMohler I dont want to load any html table in database. I have an html table I would scrap the html , parse it and then want to store that data in database. Is that clear?

Comment: You're looking to make rows and columns from a `<table>`, then bulk insert that into a database?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use jquery to convert the table into JSON data.
http://www.github.developerdan.com/table-to-json/

I would save that JSON string into a field as is. Only because I would not assume the field names to always match. But at least you'll have the data in an intelligent object you could retrieve later, and manipulate with `deserializeJSON()` as its own query: 
https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/DeserializeJSON.html

Comment: I am not so sure about the table to JSON approach. I would consider running it through `parsexml()` first and iterate over that. If course that assumes that the HTML table is XML too.